# Video file with multiple audio is not playing in wowza video on demand

Tags: audio, video, video-streaming, wowza, video-on-demand

I am using wowza streaming engine (Version 4.7) for VOD Streaming.
My requirement is to play video file with multiple audios.
I setup a plugin from github

```
https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-plugin-multitrackvod
```

for multiple audio tracks.

I also setup `SMIL file` but multiple audio is not working.
One another problem is my video.mp4 file with multiple audios is playing good in VLC but creating noise in WOWZA.

Please share a solution with me.
Example related to VOD with multiple audios will be really helpful.

MY OS is Windows 10 and i am trying to play video in Adobe HDS.

Area: Playback
Engine Version: 4.7